# Laravel mongodb very slow fetching records using wherein query

Tags: laravel, mongodb

i have a around 6gb collection with more then 7 lacks records.
trying below query
**Location::whereIn('location_id', $id)->get();**

but its taking more than 15th seconds to fetch data for 200 records i can not use pagination i need it in one go.

I am using Laravels jeneggers/mongodb package.

Comment: use DB instead eloquent model and can you have multiple id's for same location then try to use "query()"

Comment: is there any example for where in query in mongo

Answer (score 0):

Searching large data is what's taking the time, likely not the small response.

Look into adding [Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

Another option would be looking into archiving old data to make the data that's being queried shorter.

Comment: Indexing already added for location_id field

Comment: my point about large data still stands. even though it's _returning_ 200 rows it still needs to _search_ the  _6GB_ of records to collect the 200 rows. I've updated my answer to also consider archiving. If you have a 6GB table, then it's going to be a long time to query. Even if you're only querying an indexed column.